# sqlite using like command and logical operator

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

I am trying to exclude some records according to a LIKE command with a Logical OR. Individually they work but together they do not.

```
 Select CustomerName
    ,Type
    ,sum(Quantity) as Total
     ,TimeDate 
    ,date(TimeDate) as JustDate
   ,DATE(date(TimeDate),'start of month') as BeginMonth
    , DATE(date(date(TimeDate),'start of month'),'+1 month') as BeginNextMonth
    ,DATE(date(TimeDate),'start of month','+1 month','-1 day') as EndOfMonth
     ,DATE(date(TimeDate),'start of month','-1 day')  as EndOfLastMonth
    from history
    where (Type not like '%LPG%') or (Type not like '%Hyster%')
    group by type,CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake I made was to use the OR operator, Should have used AND then it works.